# How do I define a generic, generic typed property?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, generics, inheritance

So I'm trying to apply polymorphism to some view, and I'm binding this view to a common viewmodel. Here is my base abstract class:

```
public abstract class AnimalViewModel
{
    public abstract IPagedList<object> Names { get; set; }
}
```

And I have my two classes that inherit from it:

```
public class CatViewModel : AnimalViewModel
{    
    public override IPagedList<CatNameViewModel> Names { get; set; }    
}

public class DogViewModel : AnimalViewModel
{    
    public override IPagedList<DogNameViewModel> Names { get; set; }    
}
```

Note that despite my example, my `CatNameViewModel` and `DogNameViewModel` have absolutely nothing in common.

Obviously this doesn't work because the property signature of `IPagedList<object>` doesn't match that of say `IPagedList<DogNameViewModel>`

I know the normal way of solving this would be doing something like this:

```
public abstract class AnimalViewModel<T>
{
    public IPagedList<T> Names { get; set; }
}

public class CatViewModel : AnimalViewModel<CatNameViewModel>
{    

}

public class DogViewModel : AnimalViewModel<DogNameViewModel>
{    

}
```

But this has two problems, first I'm passing a generic type that isn't actually the inheriting type, and second, when I define the model to bind my view to, I still have to define a specific type to bind it to:

```
@model AnimalViewModel // doesn't work, asks to define <T>
```

And if I try to make `DogNameViewModel : INameViewModel` and `CatNameViewModel : INameViewModel` inherit from a common interface and do:

```
@model AnimalViewModel<INameViewModel> // doesn't work either
```

Is there any other way of making my "Names" property generic enough to put it in my abstract class?

Comment: Use `@model AnimalViewModel<dynamic>`. As long as the ViewModel that you are passing has the Names property implemented, you'll be fine.

Comment: I get the message: `Argument Type CatViewModel is not assignable to model of type AnimalViewModel<dynamic>` when I try to pass my model to my view via `View("ViewPage", myCatViewModel)`

Answer (score 0):

When you declare the model, you need to specify the concrete type, e.g.

```
@model AnimalViewModel< CatViewModel >
```

Simply leave the abstract class using an unbounded type .

Or do what @ganesh states (dynamic), that should work